# How to get FQDN DNS name of a kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-dns

How to get a full FQDN of the service inside Kubernetes?

```
➜ k get svc -o wide  
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                             PORT(S)    AGE     SELECTOR
airflow-flower-service   ClusterIP      172.20.119.107   <none>                                  5555/TCP   20d     app=edna-airflow
airflow-service          ClusterIP      172.20.76.63     <none>                                  80/TCP     20d     app=edna-airflow
backend-service          ClusterIP      172.20.39.154    <none>                                  80/TCP     20d     app=edna-backend
```

so how to query internal Kubernetes DNS to get the FQDN of the backend-service for example?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go inside any pod in the same namespace with `kubectl exec -ti <your pod> bash` and then run `nslookup <your service>` which will typically be, unless you change some configurations in the cluster to: `yourservice.yournamespace.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: To install nslookup utility in your pod

`apt update` and 
`apt-get install dnsutils`

Comment: apt-get is only available inside Debian derived containers. If you're not on Debian or related you need to use the package manager of your distribution and the package may be called differently.