# How to get the FQDN of a service in Istio? Are there any APIs which expose this?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, fqdn, servicemesh

I am looking for a way to represent various services running on various different meshes. So it will be helpful to know the service_name.namespace.cluster_name format and store that in a service registry.

Querying the domain from inside a pod as suggested in [How to get FQDN DNS name of a kubernetes service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732409/how-to-get-fqdn-dns-name-of-a-kubernetes-service) is not an option here.

I was wondering if Istio maintains these names internally and exposes them through any APIs?

Comment: you should be able to get it from etcd

Comment: And why to get them by querying any API or DNS at all ? As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) FQDN of a `Service` has a universal form of `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`. So if you know your cluster domain (and I assume you do if you run a `Pod` in it) and you know the `namepace`, your `Pod` is in, you also know your `Service` FQDN. If you didn't customize it, by default it will end with `svc.cluster.local` so every `Service` in such cluster will have a stable FQDN `<svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`.